# Moving label created by TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am beginner with TikZ. I have an image in my hand, and using TikZ I have crated labels. How do I move the label to the top of the image using TikZ? The following is the code I have used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usepackage{pinlabel, xcolor,vruler}  
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]

\centering
\psfig{file=fig1,scale=85}
%\caption{A concordance between $K$ and the unknot}
\label{fig:cobo}
\end{figure}
%%following code is the label code 
%I have to move the label to top of the image   
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-12,12) node {A};
\draw (-9,14) node {$\alpha$};
\draw (-5,11) node {$\beta$};
\draw (-3,16) node {$\gamma$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What image are you loading? And do you want all those nodes above the image on a straight line?

Comment: @ Alenanno sorry not image, image pdf(fig1.pdf) and I want those nodes above the image on a straight line. Is it possible to change the node to any where in the picture.

Comment: if I have sub figures are there then how I change this code. suppose I have six sub figures first row contains 3 figures and reming is in second row is it way to align these figures. (bottom alignment and space  between figure must be unique is it possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pure speculation and as help in improving your question ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\pdfcompresslevel=0
%\pdfobjcompresslevel=0

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\Large
\node (n1) [inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};
\draw
    (n1.north west) --  node[pos=0.25,above]  {$\alpha$}
                        node[pos=0.50,above]  {$\beta$}
                        node[pos=0.75,above]  {$\gamma$}
    (n1.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{A concordance between $K$ and the unknot}
\label{fig:cobo}
\end{figure}
%%following code is the label code
%I have to move the label to top of the image
\centering
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Zarko If I have sub figures are there then how I change this code. suppose I have six sub figures first row contains 3 figures and reming is in second row is it way to align these figures. (bottom alignment and space  between figure must be unique is it possible)

Comment: With `subfigure`s a situation is different. They have own (sub)captions with sub-numbers a, b, c, ... (usually in parenthesis and captions below them). Here on SE is a lot of examples with `subfigures`.